# Preprocessors directives have no effect

Tags: makefile, g++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, preprocessor-directive

I am experiencing technical difficulties with preprocessor directives :

```
#ifdef, #define
```

I have a program built by a Makefile, and I have 2 options two build it : standalone or embedded.
I did something like :

```
#ifdef _mdimode_
   //code for embedded
#else
   //code for standalone (default)
#endif
```

And in my main file when I compile in embedded purpose I wrote a :

```
#define _mdimode_
```

But it seems that g++ does not recognize or understand it. It always go in the else and never compile the code for embedded version.

*Infos:*
GNU Make 3.82
g++ (GCC) 4.6.1 20110908 (Red Hat 4.6.1-9)
file suffix : .C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess without more information. I assume the code is in a different file than the main file. If this is so then the `#define` doesn't propagate to that part of the project. You would have to set it in the file that contains the code, or in a header that is `#include`d in it.

You can also choose to set the `#define` in the options of the compilation command:

```
g++ -c -D_mdimode_ mycode.C
```